# Creating multiple new columns based on string value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I want to write a python code where I can create new multiple columns in a dataframe based on some string values seperated by comma in individual rows.

Input:

[image]

And I am expecting output as below:

[image]

Here as you can see 3 new Binary (0/1) columns namely passive, prpmoter and detractor has been created based on the values present in Segment column.

Could somebody please guide me in this.

Comment: `df.join(df['Segment'].str.get_dummies(sep=','))`

Comment: If you ask questions in the future, please be aware that a [mre] is required and images of code/data are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df['Promoter'] = df['Segment'].apply(lambda x: '1' if 
 df['Segment'].str.contains("Promoter")  else  '0')

 df['Passive'] = df['Segment'].apply(lambda x: '1' if 
 df['Segment'].str.contains("Passive")  else  '0')

 df['Detractor'] = df['Segment'].apply(lambda x: '1' if 
 df['Segment'].str.contains("Detractor")  else  '0')
```

Comment: Honestly, that's a bad approach, better stick to the duplicate.

Comment: what is bad about it? pls explain

Comment: For so many reasons. First it relies on the external state of the `df`. Second `apply` is not needed. Third this would fail with a `ValueError`, and last but not least, even if it was working this would be inefficient to repeat the process over all potential strings and you would need to know them in advance.